# Unable to copy file using batch to startup folder

Tags: batch-file, file-io, startup, windows-7-x64

I am trying to make a batch file that will copy two files from a USB to two different folders and I'm using this code

```
cd %~dp0 
mkdir c:\temp
xcopy /Y Firstfile.exe C:\temp

xcopy  /E /Y /V /I /S %cd%\secondFile.vbs "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp"
```

The first part works perfect, creates the folder and copy firstfile.exe

The problems start at the second part where I'm trying to copy secondFile.vbs to startup, 
I get no error but the file do not appear in startup folder.

I am using Windows7 -x64 enterprise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need xcopy (and some of those switches are not needed) but it should work.

Try `copy` instead and note the different path as c: may not be the drive where the users folder is stored.

Make sure you check the startup folder location

```
copy "secondFile.vbs" "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp" >nul
```

Answer (score 0):

If your batch file current path is the same of the secondFile.vbs, you don't need `%cd%`.
But, if you want to use %cd% try to surround with quotes: `%cd%\secondFile.vbs`.
I guess you don't need `/E` `/V` or `/S` arguments.